# Passport session doesn't retain after post

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm new to Node.js app, and I writing authentication by passport. I can login and  authentication routine works fine. However, after post, isAuthenticated() return false and redirect to index page. It seems like the user session is gone after doing post.

Could anybody tell me how to fix it? Here's my code.

### **app.js**

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session')
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
var manageRouter = require('./routes/manage');


var app = express();

app.use(fileUpload());
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('tiny'));
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(flash());
app.use(cookieParser('remote_teach'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({
    secret: "remote_teach",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000}
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if (req.user && req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.locals["login"] = true;
  }
  return next();
});
app.use('/manage', manageRouter);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("404");
  next(createError(404));
});


module.exports = app;
```

### **route/manage.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var file_system = require('file-system');
var fs = require('fs');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var md5 = require('md5');
const { encrypt, decrypt, randomString } = require('../crypto');
const db_configure = require('../configure');
var rootDirectory = 'public/data/';
// 資料庫
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : db_configure.db_host,
    port : db_configure.db_port,
    user : db_configure.db_user,
    password : db_configure.db_pwd,
    database : db_configure.db_name
});

// 顯示登入頁面
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.redirect('/manage/index');
    }else{
        res.render('manage/login');
    }
});
// Passport JS 登入驗證
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField: 'email',         
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true 
    },
    // Verify Callback
    function(req, email, passwd, done) {
    
        //verrify if the user is existed
    })
);
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.user_id)
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  //select user and deserialize
  done(null, user);
    
});


router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/manage',
                                   failureRedirect: '/',
                                   failureFlash: true})
);




router.post('/user/create', isAuthenticated, function(req, res, next){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = md5(req.body.password);
    connection.query('INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',[name, email, password], function (error, results, fields){
        if (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
        res.redirect('/manage/users');
    });
});



function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user && req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  return res.redirect('/');
}


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).